# "That was expected" or "That was to be expected."

Tags: grammar

When seeing something play out the way you predicted, which of the two could be said?I suspect one of the two might not even be grammatical but I cant tell which one.

Answer (score 3):

> That was expected.

This use of the passive voice generally means that those who chose the course of action expected such a result. This may refer to an acceptable side effect.

> That was to be expected.

The result was one that a reasonable and informed person ought to have predicted. Often implies a criticism of those who chose the course of action.

> That is what I expected.

The speaker foresaw the result.